# Force RedirectToAction to return to the calling view

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I have several views that submit to the same controller's ActionResult and would like the RedirectToAction statement to return to the one that called it:

```
 return RedirectToAction([view that called it], new { ID = ID });
```

thx

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Comment: i'd be for the 'close' vote too except the title might funnel someone else's search. Suggest the comment be turned to an answer so i can accept. - thx

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As an addition to the methods described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc), as Robert Harvey suggests, I would recommend using AJAX calls to the controller. Thus you don't have to return to views at all.