# Redirect to the Caller Action in ASP.NET MVC3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, action, redirecttoaction

Assume we have an action like:

```
public ActionResult Display(long Id){

  //Do something

return RedirectToAction(//To the Caller)

}
```

So `Display` action called by some Views, like:

**Index View** : `@Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", new { Id=@Model.Id } )`

So I need in `Display`: `return RedirectToAction("Index")`

Or

**Edit View** : `@Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", new { Id=@Model.Id } )`

I need in `Display`: `return RedirectToAction("Edit")`

and so on.

How can we find which action call `Display` and in the end of the action returned to the caller action? what is your suggestion?

Comment: do you want to do a RedirectToAction in display action ?

Comment: A copy of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about passing one more parameter along with id in the ActionLink method?

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", new { Id=@Model.Id ,from="Edit"} )
```

and

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", new { Id=@Model.Id ,from="Index"} )
```

and in your action method, accept that as well

```
public ActionResult Display(long Id,string from)
{

  //Not 100 % sure what you want to do with the from variable value.
   return RedirectToAction(from);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

If you don't want to pass a variable to the redirecting action method, you could also check the `Request.UrlReferrer` and use that instead.

```
public ActionResult Display(long Id){

    var caller = Request.UrlReferrer != null 
        ? Request.UrlReferrer : "DefaultRedirect";

    // do something

    return Redirect(caller);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could use a returnUrl parameter.

On the caller:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Show", "Display", new { returnUrl = this.Url.PathAndQuery })
```

and your Display action all you have to do is redirecting to the returnUrl:

```
this.Redirect(returnUrl);
```

This is flexible enough for any other case you might have in the future.