# Redirect to previous page directly from global asax

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

In `Global.asax`, in `Application_AcquireRequestState` function, I have a code which changes the language of site.

After changing the language, I want to be redirected to previous page.

How to do this ? It is ok to do in `global.asax` ?

I mention that doesn't matter on what page you are, the user must be redirected to previous page, means:

```
page1 -> change language -> page1.
```

I read [How do I redirect to the previous action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc) and I want to implement it in Global.asax but I don't know if is ok.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**I found solution**.

In `Application_AcquireRequestState`, at end of code, insert:

```
if ( this.Request.UrlReferrer != null ) {
   this.Context.Response.Redirect( this.Request.UrlReferrer.ToString() );
}
```