# How to get action from which have been redirected?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, redirect, asp.net-mvc-routing, asp.net-mvc-controller

Is there a way to get the name of the action from which I have been redirected inside a controller in ASP.NET MVC3? (By the way, without saving the name of the action in TempData nor Session)

Comment: The following post which talks about redirecting to the 'previous' action might contain the information you need: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc

Answer (score 1):

how about like this

```
public ActionResult getAction(string FromActionName){
   if(!string.IsEmptyOrNull(FromActionName)){
    //Do something with the action name
   }else{
    //Do nothing
   }
return View();
}
```

and the post action looks like

```
[HttpPost]
public ActionResult postAction(Model _model){
 //some processing
 return RedirectToAction("getAction",new{FromActionName="postAction"});
}
```

Comment: I like the idea. However, it is not quite what I'm looking for. I want to find a way to get the previous action from the data that already exists in the controller.