# MVC 5 I need the controller to open a different view based on navigation history

Tags: asp.net-mvc, controller, asp.net-mvc-5

I'm not even sure how to put this question in the title of this question (?!).

I've got a "private" view that when user is logged in, besides useful info, it also has inputs to send an email.

I don't want that private View to show if the logged in user types it into the URL of the browser. In the controller I want to check the last View that user came from and redirect him to a "public" copy of the View with no email functionality.

here is pseudo code:

```
If previous View = "xxx" Then
open private View
ELSE
open public View instead
```

Comment: You should use [Authorize] attribute, check this https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.authorizeattribute(v=vs.118).aspx

Comment: User is still logged in. He is authorized for Private and Public versions.

Comment: You can use [TempData](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12427009/2181514).

Answer (score 0):

After finding [this great SO thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc) I used some of it in the "PrivateDetailsOfStore" Controller ActionResult:

```
string previousView = Request.UrlReferrer.ToString();

if (previousView != "http://localhost/StoreMaster/Stores/PickLocation")
{
    RedirectToAction("PublicDetailsOfStore", (id));
}
```

And yes, I know I will have to change the previousView check when going into production and not using "localhost".