# MVC 4 : Back to previous page and keep search results

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

Sorry if this question has already been asked before but I couldn't find the answer so far.

I have 2 partial views updated according to searches results and from which I can access one "details" page. On that page, I have a "Back to previous page" action link (that I found here: [How do I redirect to the previous action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc)):

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { href = Request.UrlReferrer})
```

The thing is that I need to redirect to the previous page but keep the results of the search I made on it. Is there any best practices to do that?
Any help or even hint is appreciated :) 
Thanks!

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page

Comment: Thank you very much @jumpingcode !

Answer (score 1):

For those interested:

```
@Html.ActionLink("Back to previous page", null, null, null, new { onclick = "history.go(-1);"})
```

The answer proposed in the post [Onclick javascript to make browser go back to previous page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8067510/onclick-javascript-to-make-browser-go-back-to-previous-page) was given with the input tag.