# How can I redirect to the View which called another action in .net-core MVC

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-2.0

Im developing a project with ASP.NET Core 2.2 MVC. Here is a **view** named *MyView* in which there is a link which calls ***MyAction*** action.

```
<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MyAction">my link</a>
</div>
```

And this is ***MyAction*** which does st.

```
public async Task<IActionResult>MyAction(argument1,argument2)
{
    if(a condition)
    {
       it should redirect me to the view which *MyLink* is placed there.
    }
    else
    {
       return false;
    }
}
```

I want to know how can I find the url of the view(page) which called *MyAction* and redirect to it.

This is project structure(I made it simple)

[project structure](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0yCly.png)

> I found this. But I want to add NOTHING to the destination action. It doesn't work in .NET Core
>   [How do I redirect to the previous action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I redirect to the previous action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/815229/how-do-i-redirect-to-the-previous-action-in-asp-net-mvc)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### My solution

I did it. Here is how you can redirect to the view which called the action.
*Mayak* provided a good solution for it. I just added some extra information to make it secure. As he/she said,
 first,you should assign Title to all **Views**.

And after that you should pass *Path* and *QueryString* Via asp-route-returnUrl.

```
@{
     ViewData["Title"] = "MyView";
 }



<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-returnUrl="@string.Format("{0}{1}",Context.Request.Path, Context.Request.QueryString)" >my link</a>
</div>
```

Then in ***MyAction*** we pass the returnUrl as an argument

```
  public async Task<IActionResult>MyAction(string returnUrl)
    {
        if(everything is alright)
        {
            return LocalRedirect(returnUrl);
        }

        else
        {
            return false;
        }

    }
```

There is something called open redirect attack

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/security/preventing-open-redirects?view=aspnetcore-2.2

When your application receives data from a form. It's not secure and data can potentially be tampered with to redirect users to an external, malicious URL. So by using LocalRedirect you can prevent open redirect attacks.

Answer (score 2):

You can use title or specific id for every page. After you assigned ViewData["Title"] in the view (or you can use specific id for everypage without assigning title)

```
@{
    ViewData["Title"] = "MyView";
}



<div>
    <a asp-controller="Home" asp-action="MyAction" asp-route-returnUrl="@ViewData["Title"]" >my link</a>
</div>
```

Then you can use it in action

```
public async Task<IActionResult>MyAction(string returnUrl)
{


return View(returnUrl)
return RedirectToAction(returnUrl,"YourAction")
}
```

If you are gonna do something different use switch case for the reminder string like (redirecttoaction or whatever you like)

```
switch (returnUrl)
{
case"MyView":
.....
break;
case "YourView":
.....
break;
default:
...
break;
}
```