# ASP.NET MVC: How can I redirect to a previous action or a specific action after form submission?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-5

My pages have the form:

- `site.com/inventory/Query`
- `site.com/inventory/Results`
- `site.com/inventory/Details?item=123`

### View

On `Details`, I have a button to upload the item data sheet in the View:

```cs
using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file", id = "file", accept = "Application/PDF" })
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemNumber, "item")
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
}
```

The initial `Query` is a lot of work on the database (it takes about 20 seconds). Instead of returning to it, I would like to get back to the `Results` page after uploading the support document for this item on the `Detail` page.

I found a similar question:

[How do I redirect to the previous action in ASP.NET MVC?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/815229/22019322)

I modified my code to include this **Redirect**:

### Controller

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string item)
{
    // saves the file (code hidden)
    return Redirect($"{Request.UrlReferrer}");
}
```

However, the **Redirect** above successfully returns me to the `Details` page.

Is there a way to redirect all the way back to the `Results` page?

### Update

I have tried updating to this, based on the answer below:

```cs
[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken()]
public ActionResult Upload(HttpPostedFileBase file, string item)
{
    // saves the file (code hidden)
    var model = Session["InventoryModelObject"] as InventoryModel;
    return RedirectToAction("Results", model);
}

[HttpPost]
[ValidateAntiForgeryToken]
public ActionResult Results(InventoryModel model)
{
    var list = new List<Source>();
    list.AddRange(model.GateWaySelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.BowSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.CuddySelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.WSSSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.DeckSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.ASelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.RSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    list.AddRange(model.PSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2));
    var dlnSql = "";
    foreach (var item in list)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlnSql))
        {
            dlnSql = " AND DAMDLN IN (";
        }
        dlnSql += $"'{item.Item1}', ";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(dlnSql))
    {
        dlnSql += "' ')";
    }
    var statusSource = model.StatusSelectedSources.Where(x => x.Item2);
    var statSql = "";
    if (statusSource.Any(x => x.Item1 == "RT"))
    {
        statSql = " AND DASTAT IN ('RT', ";
    }
    if (statusSource.Any(x => x.Item1 == "SN"))
    {
        statSql = string.IsNullOrEmpty(statSql) ? " AND DASTAT IN ('SN', " : statSql + "'SN', ";
    }
    if (statusSource.Any(x => x.Item1 == "DL"))
    {
        statSql = string.IsNullOrEmpty(statSql) ? " AND DASTAT IN ('DL', " : statSql + "'DL', ";
    }
    if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(statSql))
    {
        statSql += "' ') ";
    }
    var yearSql = "";
    if (!model.AllYears && model.YearSelectedSources.Any(x => x.Item2))
    {
        foreach (var item in model.YearSelectedSources)
        {
            if (item.Item2)
            {
                yearSql += $"'{item.Item1}', ";
            }
        }
        if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(yearSql))
        {
            yearSql = $" AND DAPRGY IN ({yearSql} '0') ";
        }
    }
    var sql = $@"
SELECT DASTAT, DADTRS, TRIM(DASRNO) AS DASRNO, DAMDLN, DAORNO, DAENGD, DAEXTC, DACONF, DACUST, DADTIN
FROM {ViewBag.Library}.DLRINVAPF
WHERE DADLRN={Session["DealershipID"]}{yearSql}{statSql}{dlnSql}";
    Session["InventoryModelObject"] = model;
    return View(result);
}
```

But this is trying to send my model as a JSON string parameter instead of calling the method that accepts the model.

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fRwzV.png)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There isn't any "double back" in ASP.NET MVC. But you could redirect to the desired view using one of two approaches

1. In case you have a permanent flow you could just redirect to desired action providing the required parameter to restore view

```
return RedirectToAction("Results", ...);
```

2. Add `returnUrl` query or post form parameter to redirect to after form submitted. For example:

```
using (Html.BeginForm("Upload", "Inventory", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
    @Html.TextBox("file", "", new { type = "file", id = "file", accept = "Application/PDF" })
    <input type="hidden" name="returnUrl" value="@Request.UrlReferrer" />
    @Html.HiddenFor(m => m.ItemNumber, "item")
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary">Upload</button>
}
```

Or you could put that into the URL query string.

Comment: I am getting `The resource cannot be found.` If it helps, `Results` takes a Model parameter, which I have code to fill if it is null.

Comment: If you have a model with multiple parameters then Redirect to action is your way

Comment: I tried passing the model, but it converted it into a json string and used it as a parameter (see updated question)

Comment: When you RedirectToAction you have to pass route Params, but not the model itself. After the redirect the target action should build/fetch model based on route parameters and call `return View(model);`

Comment: Can you show your results action method too?

Comment: Updated question to show `ActionResult Results(InventoryModel model)`

Comment: Oh! Results annotated as Post only action method. Do you really need that? in that can you can either support Get too or make a call from you javascript.

Comment: Sadly, yes. The original `Query` is a **POST** to the `Results`. Maybe it can't be done with ASP.NET MVC

Comment: In that case you can firstly redirect to details or any dummy page, and after that make a Ajax/Form Post request to Results.

Comment: Please investigate this approach https://stackoverflow.com/q/133925/2091519 it will allow you to either generate form with require parameters or populate existing and submit when page load or timeout. So you will be auto redirected from Details to Results